# sending output stream to char[] in c

Tags: c, stdout, freopen

I have been using `dup` and `freopen` to rerout `stdout` to a file as below:

```
fflush(stdout);
fgetpos(stdout, &pos);
fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
freopen("stdout.out", "w", stdout);
```

What I would like to do would be rerout it to a `char[]`, so that I can manipulate it.  obviously this isn't very useful when writing with `printf`, but when using libraries that write to `stdout`, it would be helpful to get the output in the code so I can manipulate it, if necessary.

Comment: Why is reading the file into memory unacceptable?

Comment: @user315052 it just seems like an extra step to write to a file then read from that file immediately later.  can the output not be sent directly to the `char[]`?

Comment: There is no API to change `stdout` into a memory stream. GNU's libc provides `fmemopen` and `open_memstream`, but they create new streams, and there is no interface to make one stream replace an existing stream.

Comment: This is the mirrored version of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558772/how-to-get-file-descriptor-of-buffer-in-memory

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to stdout is not guaranteed to work, but maybe it will work on your platform, otherwise see this answer based on shmem_open, mmap and fmem_open: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25327235/2332068