# Is this code safe for opening a buffer in memory as a file?(Code appears to work)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file descriptor of buffer in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558772/how-to-get-file-descriptor-of-buffer-in-memory)

I'm trying to force a library that uses a `FILE` class to use a buffer in memory instead of a file. I tried `fmemopen`, however, the library uses `fileno` which returns -1 and causes the library to crash. So I read that I need a file descriptor and I could use the pipe command to make one. I don't fully understand what I did but I got it to work. However, I don't know if what I did is actually safe. So here is the code:

```
int fstr[2];
pipe(fstr);
write(fstr[1], src, strlen(src));
close(fstr[1]);
FILE* file = fdopen( fstr[0], "r" );
```

So is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a file handle, this is as good as anything I can think of.

One possible issue you may run into is that the buffer size for a pipe is limited.  If your string is larger than the buffer size, the `write(...)` to the pipe will block until some data is `read(...)` from the other end.

Ideally you would have a worker thread writing to the pipe, but if this is not possible/too hard, you can possibly adjust the pipe buffer size through [`fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, ...)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fmemopen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) instead. This function already facilitate writing/reading to/from memory buffer for you.

Comment: Btw - offtopic - I've never understood what that `(3)` means in the `man` page identifiers? And why are you using the `man` page identifier in the first place?

Comment: If the OP needs a file descriptor, this will not work. *"There is no file descriptor associated with the file stream returned by these functions (i.e., fileno(3) will return an error if called on the returned stream)."*

Comment: @Vilx-: man pages are split into sections; section 3 deals with standard library routines (et al).

Comment: The OP explicitly said he has already tried `fmemopen`.  You should probably address his problems in your answer.

Comment: @Vilx- for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections