# Redirect FILE handle to char-buffer

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm using a third-party library that allows conversion between two file formats *A* and *B*. I would like to use this library to load a file of format *A* and convert it to format *B*, but I only need the converted representation in memory. So I would like to do the conversion without actually saving a file of the target format to disk and rather obtain an `unsigned char*` buffer or something similar. Unfortunately the libraries only conversion function is of the form

```
void saveAsB(A& a, std::FILE *const file);
```

What can I do? Is there any way to redirect the write operations performed on the handle to some buffer?

Comment: You may look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558772/how-to-get-file-descriptor-of-buffer-in-memory

Comment: If the library dynamically loads `fwrite()` from a DLL (MSVCRT, for example), you can try DLL injection to hook on `fwrite()`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Injection, although http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/13/6648400.aspx. The sanest, however, is to write to a temporary file and then read it back into memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your platform supports it, use [open_memstream(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html).  This will be available on Linux and BSD systems, and it's probably better than fmemopen() for your use case because open_memstream() allocates the output buffer dynamically rather than you having to know the maximum size in advance.

If your platform doesn't have those functions, you can always use a "RAM disk" approach, which again on Linux would be writing a "file" to `/dev/shm/` which will never actually reach any disk, but rather be stored in memory.

Edit: OK, so you say you're using Windows.  Here's an outline of what you can try:

- Open a [non-persisted memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).
- Use [_open_osfhandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) to convert the HANDLE to an int file descriptor.
- Use [_fdopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dye30d82%28VS.80%29.aspx) to convert the int file descriptor to FILE*.
- Cross your fingers.  I haven't tested any of this.

I found this reference useful in putting the pieces together: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1044/A-Handy-Guide-To-Handling-Handles

Edit 2: It looks like CreateFileMapping() and _open_osfhandle() may be incompatible with each other--you would be at least the third person to try it:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/NTGL3h7L1LY
- http://www.progtown.com/topic178214-createfilemapping-and-file.html

So, you can try what the last link suggested, which is to use `setvbuf()` to "trick" the data into flowing to a buffer you control, but even that has potential problems, e.g. it won't work if the library seeks within the FILE*.

So, perhaps you can just write to a file on some temporary/scratch filesystem and be done with it?  Or use a platform other than Windows?  Or use some "RAM disk" software.

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on POSIX being available, then use [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html).