# Fast read stdin into buffer with no checking

Tags: c++, io, buffer, stdin

I have buffer, let's say 65536 bytes long. How can I read stdin into that buffer as fast as possible (using IO hardware) without any check for newline or '\0' characters. I have a guarantee that the number of characters in stdin will always match my buffer.

So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 65536

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFFER_LENGTH);

    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];

    // now read stdin into buffer
    // fast print:
    puts(buffer);    // given buffer is null terminated

    return 0;
}
```

Is there something similar to `puts()` that will fast read into buffer instead of console?

Comment: Not sure I understand the request.  Does [fread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) look like what you want?

Comment: @AProgrammer Yeah, fread works. I just didn't know you could pass stdin as FILE*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C's standard [`fread()` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 65536

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFFER_LENGTH);

    // need space to terminate the C-style string
    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH + 1];

    // eliminate stdin buffering too
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, BUFFER_LENGTH);    

    // now read stdin into buffer
    size_t numRead = fread( buffer, 1, BUFFER_LENGTH, stdin );

    // should check for errors/partial reads here

    // fread() will not terminate any string so it
    // has to be done manually before using puts()
    buffer[ numRead ] = '\0';

    // fast print:
    puts(buffer);    // given buffer is null terminated

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `puts()` inserts newline at the end. You can use `fputs(buffer, stdout);` to manage newlines yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If `puts` gives you the behavior you want except for the fact that it outputs to stdout, you could use [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) to pipe stdout to a different file descriptor (don't forget to reconnect stdout when you're done).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955962/how-to-buffer-stdout-in-memory-and-write-it-from-a-dedicated-thread) shows a good example of redirecting output in C, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558772/how-to-get-file-descriptor-of-buffer-in-memory) has an example of getting a file descriptor for a buffer in memory.