# AMediaExtractor gives an error in one case and doesn't in other, why?

Tags: android, c++, native, android-mediacodec

I need to pass to `MediaExtractor` the data, for this purpose I use this method `SetDataSource`

https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#amediaextractor_setdatasourcefd

Like this:

```
int32_t NDK_extractor::decode()
{
   
    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    media_status_t err;
    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
    fp = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.debug/files/Models/test.mp3", "rb");


    if (fp)
    {
        err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(ex, fileno(fp), 0, dataSize);
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Failed open file");
        return 0;
    }

    if (err != AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        LOGE("SOUND :: Error setting ex data source, err %d", err);
        return 0;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

And it works fine, but now I need to work with pointer to data and data size, so I changed this method like this

```
int32_t NDK_extractor::decode()
{

    FILE *fp = nullptr;
    media_status_t err;
    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
    fp = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.debug/files/Models/test.mp3", "rb");



    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long lSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    void *buf = new unsigned char[lSize];
    fread(buf, 1, lSize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fmemopen(buf, lSize, "r");
    
    
    
    if (fp)
    {
        err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(ex, fileno(fp), 0, dataSize);
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("Failed open file");
        return 0;
    }

    if (err != AMEDIA_OK)
    {
        LOGE("SOUND :: Error setting ex data source, err %d", err);
        return 0;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

So, I am reading the same data (as in previous ex.) in buffer also getting a size and then I open it with `fmemopen` and as a result getting such an error - AMEDIA_ERROR_BASE

What is a problem here? Why does it work in one case and doesn't in other in spite of it is almost the same? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, the problem turned out to be that `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd` method accepts a file descriptor as a parameter. In order to get a file descriptor from `FILE`, you need to call `fileno()` method on `FILE` that was opened with `fopen()` then everything works well, but if the file was opened with `fmemopen()` then `fileno()` returns -1. I tried to do it through a pipe https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559018/5709159, but this approach does not work for `AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd` (I think because the pipe does not support seek()) tried to do it through a custom `MediaExtractor` (one of methods setDataSource()), but it was introduced only with api 29 (it does not suit me very much) in the end I did it with a workaround- I get the bytes, write to a temporary file and open this file with `fopen()` and call `fileno()` get the file descriptor and pass it to `setDataSouceFd()`